# icons not appearing properly after installing plasma 5

Tags: icons, plasma-5

I installed Plasma5 in UBuntu running Unity. The installation went fine however, the icons for KDE are not showing up properly. 
I tried deleting the `/var/tmp/kdecache-$USER/icon-cache.kcache` but it didn’t help.

How can I get this fixed?

Attaching screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by changing the values in *Settings -> Application Style -> Gtk Style*

- Select a Gtk2 Theme -> Oxygen-GTK
- Select a GTK3 Theme -> Oxygent- GTK
- Font -> Ubuntu 10
- Set Icon Theme -> Breeze
- Set Fallback Theme -> Oxygen